# Choice of natural isomorphisms in category theory

Tags: category-theory

Let us consider two categories $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{D}$ and two functors $F:\mathbf{A} \to \mathbf{B}$ and $G:\mathbf{B} \to \mathbf{A}$. One says that $F$ and $G$ form an *equivalence* if there are natural isomorphisms
$$
F \circ G \simeq\mathrm{id},\qquad G \circ F \simeq \mathrm{id}.
$$
Can there exist more than one way to choose such isomorphisms? If we include the requirement that these isomorphisms satisfy the triangle identities does it change anything?

Comment: In general there is more than one choice for an isomorphism $F \circ G \simeq \mathrm{id}$. The number of choices is parametrized by the automorphisms of the identity functor. You will find that in many cases, the identity functor has no nontrivial automorphisms.

Comment: @Julian: Thanks for the explanation! What is an example of a category with non-trivial automorphisms of the identity?

Comment: Take the category of groups with homomorphisms and antihomomorphisms, i.e. $f(ab) = f(b)f(a)$. Then inversion is a nontrivial automorphism of every object and is functorial, giving rise to a nontrivial automorphism of the identity.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Or easier: Take negation on the category of abelian groups. I think the automorphism group of the identity functor on $\mathrm{Ab}$ is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.